# How to configure linux/apache for multiple virtualhost in local machine

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, debian, virtualhost

I have two local web site project, localgoogle.com and localapple.com.

`localgoogle.com` files are in `/home/vahid/dev/localgoogle`

`localapple.com` files are in `/home/vahid/dev/localapple`

My OS is debian 8.5, I have apache2 installed.

I made `/etc/apache2/sites-available/localgoogle.com.conf`

and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/localapple.com.conf`

both linked to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and enabled by a2ensite command.

This is `localgoole.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localgoogle.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localgoogle.com
    DocumentRoot /home/vahid/dev/localgoogle
    ServerAlias www.localgoogle.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

localapple conf file follow above configuration rule.

I restarted apache2 service, but I don't know why and how to access this virtualhosts from browser!

I tried `localhost/localgoogle.com` in browser but It's return Not Found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the site directly as **localgoogle.com** from your browser. Make sure that the name resolves to your local ip address using hosts file or dns.

Comment: What the f :D. tnx ;)